# How Python can run R scripts without writing them into R files?

Tags: python, r, plot

I have a python script that analyzes some datasets and the results are written in separate files. I'd like to generate some plots for this analysis and for some reasons I have to produce my plots by using R. I'm using my python script to generate small R scripts that produces the plots. However, I write the R scripts in hard disk and my Python code executes Rscript command to have my plots generated. It's not a nice solution of course! 
Is there a way to directly stream the R commands into R without me needing to make a R script file?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget he does mention that he *has* to use R for plotting

Comment: well I'm familiar with IPython, but I have another question. How can I make Python talks to R directly? My solution is to write my R code in a file and pass the file to R, but is there any other way to pass it directly via memory?

Answer (score 5):

Use rpy2 ([link](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)).  You can run R from directly in your Python script.

[Here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/graphics.html) is the specific documentation for plotting using rpy2.